# Hadoop delimiter not working for standalone machine

Tags: java, hadoop, delimiter

I am relatively new to Hadoop. I set up hadoop 0.20.2 in my local machine using this [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/01/hadoop-modes-explained-standalone.html). Used a working code (tested successfully on another machine) and ran it on my machine. Everything worked properly without error, except for the fact that the delimiter in the driver class is not delimiting. Its suppose to send me blocks of input, but still sends me the input on a per line basis.

My driver class looks like this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter","\n\n\n");

    Job job = new Job(conf);
    job.setJobName("Aggregated occurence");

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setJarByClass(EntityCoOccurence.class);
    job.setMapperClass(CoOccuringEntityMap.class);
    job.setReducerClass(CoOccuringEntityCountReduce.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.submit();
}
```

My input file is made up of 3 lines of text and then 2 lines blank. Something like this -

```
abc
def
ghi


abc
dfg
sas


pos
sdf
sfd
```

The delimiter works perfectly in my university hadoop cluster, but doesn't work in my local machine. I printed out the input and found that hadoop sends me each line as input inspite of the delimiter. Any Ideas?

### Edit

I was looking into it a little more and found that the **TextInputFormat** class in the hadoop-0.20.2-core jar's recordReader method looks like this -

```
 @Override
  public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> 
    createRecordReader(InputSplit split,
                       TaskAttemptContext context) {
    return new LineRecordReader();
  }
```

This should be something like this -

```
 @Override
  public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text>
    createRecordReader(InputSplit split,
                       TaskAttemptContext context) {
// By default,textinputformat.record.delimiter = ‘/n’(Set in configuration file)
    String delimiter = context.getConfiguration().get(
        "textinputformat.record.delimiter");
    byte[] recordDelimiterBytes = null;
    if (null != delimiter)
      recordDelimiterBytes = delimiter.getBytes();
    return new LineRecordReader(recordDelimiterBytes);
  }
```

But, I am bound by the version. Can anybody suggest something?

Answer (score 1):

custom delimiter (provided by “textinputformat.record.delimiter” parameter) is not supported on version 1.2.1 of Hadoop. However, you can still create your own record reader to handle that particular case.

Try giving String delimitor='\n\n\n' in your line record reader instead of pulling it from context object.

Comment: Umm..what do u mean on version 1.2.1. I am using version 0.20.2. do you mean till version 1.2.1. In any case, I did construct a customLineReader based on the example in this link - https://github.com/aamend/hadoop-recordreader . It works fine now. Thanks.